# opencv linemod throwing runtime errors

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am using opencv-2.4.6 and trying to run a simple program to use the `cv::linemod` functionality.

Here is my code:

```
    #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h> 
    #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    cv::Ptr<cv::linemod::Detector> detector;
    detector = cv::linemod::getDefaultLINEMOD();

    Mat depth = imread("input/duck/duck_650_depth2.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
    Mat color = imread("input/duck/duck_650_rgb2.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR);

    Mat object_mask = Mat(depth.rows, depth.cols, CV_32S);

    for (int x = 0; x < depth.cols; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < depth.rows; y++) {
            if (depth.at<int16_t>(y, x) > 0) {
                object_mask.at<int>(y, x) = 1;
            } else {
                object_mask.at<int>(y, x) = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    vector<Mat> sources;
    sources.push_back(color);
    sources.push_back(depth);
    std::string class_id = cv::format("class%d", 1);
    Mat display = color.clone();
    Rect bb;

    int template_id = detector->addTemplate(sources, class_id, object_mask, &bb);
    if (template_id != -1) {
        cout << " added template " << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which compiles fine, however at runtime I get this error:

```
OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (Unsupported data type (=4)) in getMorphologyRowFilter, file /home/aly/libs/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/imgproc/src/morph.cpp, line 894
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/aly/libs/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/imgproc/src/morph.cpp:894: error: (-213) Unsupported data type (=4) in function getMorphologyRowFilter
```

I don't really understand what it means? I am using the latest opencv version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the algorithm. But the error message appears because you are using a matrix format that is not supported by the morphological functions of OpenCV.

It seems only CV_8U, CV_16U, CV_16S and CV_32F are supported.

Does it solve your problem if you add

```
object_mask.convertTo(object_mask, CV_8U);
```

before you call the `addTemplate` function?

Comment: You're a lifesaver, I would +2 if I could